# Create a new class with derived fields without duplicating field names

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, properties, duplicates

In Kotlin, how can I derive fields from a base definition (abstract, interface, inheritance, something else) without explicitly overriding them?

The closest I can get is:

```
abstract class Person {
    open val name: String = "Stranger"
}

data class Doctor(
    override val name: String,
    val yearsOfExperience: Int
): Person()

val doc = Doctor(yearsOfExperience = 20, name = "Eric")
```

But ideally, since I have a use case of an unchangeable model with hundreds of fields, I would like to have:

```
abstract class Person {
    open val name: String = "Stranger"
}

data class Doctor(
    val yearsOfExperience: Int
): Person()

val doc = Doctor(yearsOfExperience = 20, name = "Eric")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If you want `Doctor` to be able to change `Person.name` to anything other than what's defined in `Person`, you are by definition overriding the behavior in `Person` - Kotlin is just forcing you to make that contract explicit.

If it didn't do that, it would be possible to do something like this:

```
data class Doctor(
    val yearsOfExperience: Int
) : Person()
```

Then later decide to add a `name` field:

```
data class Doctor(
    val yearsOfExperience: Int,
    val name: String = "Doctor"
) : Person
```

Now `Doctor.name` has a default value of `"Doctor"` which is different to the expected behavior defined in `Person`. Previous code that did `Doctor(yearsOfExperience = 20)` will now behave differently - it will get the `name` "`Doctor"` instead of `"Stranger"`. Kotlin is making sure that you realise that, and explicitly ask for it by adding the `override` modifier.

So you can omit the fields you want to inherit, but not the ones you want to override.